# Use Kong to expose Konga

Tags: dockerfile, kong, docker-stack

I am using Kong to expose Konga - which is a UI for the Kong admin interface.

I am running it using docker stack with the following dockerfile:

```
version: "3.1"

secrets:
  webservices_hostname:
    external: true
  webservices_cert:
    external: true
  webservices_key:
    external: true

services:

#Create a new empty database for kong to use
# postgress used instead of cassendra as I haven't been able to find a healthcheck command for cassendra
  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.4
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

#Setup kong database
  kong-migration:
    image: kong
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
    command: kong migrations up
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

#Start the kong server
  kong:
    image: kong
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    secrets:
     - webservices_cert
     - webservices_key
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
      - KONG_SSL_CERT=/run/secrets/webservices_cert
      - KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY=/run/secrets/webservices_key
    ports:
      - 80:8000
      - 443:8443
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -I -s -L http://127.0.0.1:8000 || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
    restart: on-failure

#The next section starts a UI for kong called konga. 
#We only need a ui for development experimentation and can be removed if no UI is required
# when it is running it can be accessed on port 1337
  konga:
    image: pantsel/konga
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
     - 1337:1337

#Configure kong to forward requests to flaskapp
  kong-addapis-konga:
    image: byrnedo/alpine-curl
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    command: "-i -X POST \
                --url http://kong:8001/apis/ \
                --data 'name=flaskapp' \
                --data 'uris=/flaskapp' \
                --data 'upstream_url=http://flaskapp:80'
                --data 'https_only=false'
             "
```

I start the stack with the command

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file ./docker-compose.yml webservices
```

If I access host:1337 Konga will work as normal. I can go to connections and it connects to the kong admin api without a problem (http://kong:8001)

However if I access https://host:443/konga or http://host:80/konga it gets to konga without a problem, however when I try and get konga to connect to kong I get an error:

"Oh snap! Can't connect to http://kong:8001"

Why would accessing Konga via Kong be causing this behavior? I thought that it doesn't matter how I connect to Konga - once I get there there should be no difference between using a directly exposed port or going through Kong.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a network and connect it to kong. Use created network in your konga configuration.

```
docker network create my-net

docker network connect my-net kong

docker run --rm --network my-net -p 8080:8080 pantsel/konga start --kong-url http://kong:8001
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, adding a slash to the end of the route solved the issue. 
instead of http://host:80/konga call http://host:80/konga/
So the route will be instead of /konga, /konda/